# Is there software to test and view LDAP connections and responses?

Tags: testing, ldap

I'm new to using LDAP.  Is there any software that I can use to connect to an LDAP server and execute a search and view the output?  For example ,something like SoapUI is to WSDL connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many LDAP clients out there. There's one at www.userbooster.de, the freeware version of UserBooster client. There is JXplorer, which runs in a Java Virtual Machine. Many more.